# Multiple labels in chartjs with stacked bars on angular 4

Tags: json, angular, chart.js

[image: chart labels]

My problem is that I have to display one label for each bar but i can't because when i add labels to the json chartjs add new group of empty bars 
as I show in the picture, I'm using stacked bars, how I can do that?.

Here is my Json code.

```
  PredialUrbano = {
    type: 'groupableBar',
    labels: ['Facturado','cobrado','ejemplo'],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Facturado',
            data: [67.8],
            backgroundColor: '#3A3032',
            stack: 1
        }, {
            label: 'Exento',
            data: [20.7],
            backgroundColor: '#902528', 
            stack: 1
        },
        {
            label: 'Ley de ingresos',
            data: [20.7],
            backgroundColor: '#902528', 
            stack: 2
        },
        {
            label: 'Cobrado',
            data: [20.7],
            backgroundColor: '#3A3032', 
            stack: 3
        }
    ],
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{ stacked: true }],
            yAxes: [{ stacked: true }]
        }
    },
};
```